# People approved for events can't register

Tags: civievent, pending

Folks who get the email with the confirmation link in it to go and register for an event are now getting a page that says this:
You have not been added to the waiting list because there are spaces available for this event. We recommend registering yourself for an available space instead.

Process:

They get the email saying they have been approved with a link to confirm.

They click the link and get taken to a page with two options:
cancel registration
confirm registration

You click on "confirm registration".

The next page is the registration page for this event with all the fields filled in with what they'd already given.

Click the "review" button.

Next page says this at the top:

Please correct the following errors in the form fields below:
You have not been added to the waiting list because there are spaces available for this event. We recommend registering yourself for an available space instead.

Using 5.71.1 on Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

Can you log this as a bug over at gitlab? https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/new

Comment: Yes, I can do that tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: I guess I didn't have an account hey. Just applied. I'll post it as soon as I get approved.

Comment: Well, still waiting on approval for my account, so I haven't been able to post it.